# Problem with simple function in C

Tags: c

I am new in C and I have problem with compiling this code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void suma( int a, int b, int wynik)
{
    wynik=0;
    printf("a=\n");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("b=\n");
    scanf("%d",&b);
    wynik=a+b;
    printf("wynik = %d",&wynik);
}


int main()
{
    suma(int a, int b, int wynik);
}
```

I don't know why but compiler tells me that 2 argument has type int * insted of int. I dont' know what does it mean and where I made mistake.

Comment: In future, please format your code (use the `{}` button or add four spaces at the start of the line) :)

Comment: Also, show us the actual error.

Comment: If you want to store the result of the sum inside the wynik variable be shure to write it like this

    void suma( int a, int b, int &wynik)


Declaring the variable this way will store the result inside the wynik variable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
printf("wynik = %d",&wynik);
```

to

```
printf("wynik = %d",wynik);
```

Otherwise you'll be printing the address of `wynik` as an integer.

Also the way you call `suma` makes no sense.

Comment: Also, the call to suma should be fixed. It is currently a function declaration (if that).

Comment: @Lars Wirzenius I think I noticed it as you were writing your comment:)) good call

Comment: So how to write a simple function which adds two ints?

Answer (score 0):

change `printf("wynik = %d",&wynik);` to `printf("wynik = %d",wynik);`

and also you don't seem to need the arguments of suma.

**Try this:**

```
void suma()
{
    int a,b,wynik;
    wynik=0;
    printf("a=\n");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("b=\n");
    scanf("%d",&b);
    wynik=a+b;
    printf("wynik = %d",wynik);
}


int main()
{
    suma();
}
```